# OSX / Accessing Chrome Local Policies

Tags: macos, google-chrome, group-policy

A few years ago, I set a [policy for Chrome](http://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3) on my Mac.

I can see this policy and its value via `chrome://policy`. It says that it applies to "Current user". But for the life of me I can't remember where the local policy file is stored.

Oddly, I can't find anything on Google (though I vaguely remember having difficulty finding this location when I first set the policy value). I have looked in ~/Library/Application Support, ~/Library/Preferences, ~/Library/Google, and their corresponding directories at root.

Any ideas? This is really bugging me.

I'm currently doing a full-hardrive search for the string, so if I find the file, I'll post an answer.

Comment: So after searching my disk, I only found localization files... no preference files. Which means it may be a binary-encoded plist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welp, I fixed it.

**TL; DR**: always check `~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist`!

Who would have thought that there would be *hidden preferences* in an *already hidden* directory? Not me, for sure.

`.GlobalPreferences.plist` is used for universal settings — highlight color, spelling, keyboard & mouse, etc. — that apply to all applications. Applications will also check this file for their own Preference keys. However, because it was hidden, I didn't think to check it.

I found the key that was causing the policy issue, deleted it, and relogged (**required**). No more issue.

I'm not sure *why* past-me put the preference in this file (bad idea), rather than in Chrome's plist file (which exists in the same directory!).

---

A side note — the reason why I wasn't finding the key in my full-drive searches:
The plist looks something like this (abbreviated):

```
...
<key>PolicyNameWasHere</key><integer>1</integer>
...
```

My search program, apparently, was only looking for that word, not the string. Due to the lack of whitespace, it didn't get picked up.